# How to return two values in a return and cache them in two variables in one line of code in python?

Tags: python, return

I need to return two values in a single return, then I need to obtain the result of the function in two variables without having to access the tuple that sends the return by indices, obtain it in a single line and assign it to two other variables at the same time.

Comment: Something like `x, y = f(z)`?

Comment: yes, I solved it later friend, I share it for whoever it helps, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it in the following way, each value that returns the return assigns it to a variable in a single line

```
def return_two_values():
    return "a", "b"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    letter1, letter2 = return_two_values()
    print(letter1)
    print(letter2)
```

Results:

```
a
b
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the value in a tuple?

```
def return_two_value():
    return(1,2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    (x,y) = return_two_values()
```